# Solution for fractional operation "N-ation of N by N"

Tags: notation, arithmetic, big-numbers

A lot of [articles](https://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/bignumbers.html) seems to be concerned with "unimaginably" large numbers, leading to a conclusion that we just do not have sufficiently good notation for dealing with such numbers.

So imagine we have a discrete Ackermann sequence based function that has values of:

```
A(1) = 1
A(2) = 2+2 = 4
A(3) = 3*3*3 = 27
A(4) = ⁴4 ≈ 10 ^ (10 ^ 154)
```

**How can we compute the value of `A(3.5)`? Let's call it `3.5⇑`. The function should be defined over reals ≥ 1 and have all of its n-th derivatives smooth. The approach should produce a practically usable function body for small parameter values even though it may become unbound as parameter grows.**

If we use the N-ation of N notation, we can get rid of hype of large numbers in math not unlike how scientific notation allowed getting rid of too large or too small numbers in physics.

Most of commonly used numbers will fit between 3⇑ and 4⇑.

Predicated on that we can calculate what's 3.2⇑ + 3.4⇑.

The fact that we cannot "write down" large numbers⇑ such as 15⇑ should not discourage us - math operations may still be carried out on them. After all, it's not like physicists decry the impracticality of writing down Avogadro number in simple decimal notation.

Comment: There is no question here. Mathematicians invent notations that allow them to talk about the structures (and numbers) that matter in any particular context.

Comment: The question here is how to calculate A(fractional number) or `fractional number⇑` @EthanBolker

Comment: OK I see the question. A better question might be how to _define_ that number. You need that definition before you can think about calculating it. By analogy, you need a definition of $2^{1/2}$ before you can calculate it. Thinking of exponentiation as repeated multiplication won't do.

Comment: @EthanBolker Correct - that's what I am asking. How do we define A(frac)?

Comment: Why not start by asking just for a definition of $A(3/2)$? What properties should "halfway to addition" have?

Comment: "How do we define A(frac)?" Easy! $A(r) = 0\ \forall r \notin \Bbb N$. Done. What? You say that is worthless? Well, it doesn't fit your nebulous hopes, I admit. But you didn't specify any particular conditions that the function must satisfy, so this does meet all the actual requirements you offered. Of course, uncountably many other functions would as well, but without something more, how are we to choose between them? How about you figure out what you really need from this function, instead of expecting others to make guesses?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Then I would have the answer already and would not ask the question.

Comment: You are demanding us to produce something for which there are **uncountably many** choices (that means *strictly more* than just infinitely many choices). You are not going to find many people here foolish enough to keep pulling random things out of their posterior for you in hopes that you will eventually be satisfied.

Comment: I've clarified my requirements @PaulSinclair

Comment: Better. But there are still infinitely many choices. You can assume the function is analytic (representable by power series). That still leaves infinitely many choices, but one can begin to organize them at this point, and choose the simplest, up to a few arbtrary constants. The theory is part of complex analysis, but I've have to go look some stuff up to say much more, and I don't have the right references available right now. If someone doesn't provide before, I'll say more when I can.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Find one of these, or disprove that they exist - get a nice green check :)

Comment: I'm sure you could whip something up that satisfies these criteria.  But it might not be very satisfying. The usual way to generalize integer-valued $f(n)$ to continuous ones $g(x)$ is to find a fairly simple, "natural" function $g(x)$ with $g(n) = f(n)$. For example, if $f(n) = 2^n$ then we can use $g(x) = \exp(n \log 2))$, or if $f(n) = n!$ we can use $g(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^x \, dt$, the (shifted) Gamma function. I don't know if there's a nice way to do that in this case.